# Http Get Method in Xcode

Tags: iphone, xcode, ipad

I need to create a Http Get Method in Xcode to connect to a host. The http method with cookie likes that :

```
Cookie: RouteID=route.neo_srv02; username=01216332476; __utma=72292239.948454815.1294242721.1294288226.1294301327.5; __utmz=72292239.1294242721.1.1.utmcsr=(direct)|utmccn=(direct)|utmcmd=(none)
```

I don't how to do that, how to set Cookie and in addition connect via proxy.

Comment: It is not clear from your question if you want to do this from Xcode, or if you want to make some code for iPhone/iPad (through Xcode) that does this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

//Initiate connection

```
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init] autorelease];
[request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];

//keep adding your headers this way

NSString *accept = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"application/xml,application/xhtml+xml,text/html;q=0.9,text/plain;q=0.8,image/png,*/*;q=0.5"];

[request addValue:accept forHTTPHeaderField: @"Accept"];

//send request & get response

NSData *returnData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];
```

Comment: Sorry but i need to set cookie, not get? Assume that i have a cookie value. I need to use http method get with that cookie to get information.

Comment: NSString cookie = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"RouteID=route.neo_srv02; username=01216332476; __utma=72292239.948454815.1294242721.1294288226.1294301327.5; __utmz=72292239.1294242721.1.1.utmcsr=(direct)|utmccn=(direct)|utmcmd=(none)"];

[request addValue:cookie forHTTPHeaderField: @"Cookie"];

Answer (score 1):

For Get Method...Example sending text

```
NSURL * serviceUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://.......url"];
NSMutableURLRequest * serviceRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:serviceUrl];
[serviceRequest setValue:@"text" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-type"];

[serviceRequest setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];
[serviceRequest setValue:@"asd" forHTTPHeaderField:@"username"];
[serviceRequest setValue:@"asd" forHTTPHeaderField:@"password"];


//Get Responce hear----------------------   
NSURLResponse *response;
NSError *error;
NSData *urlData=[NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:serviceRequest returningResponse:&response error:&error];
NSString *strdata=[[NSString alloc]initWithData:urlData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]; 
NSLog(@"%@",strdata);
```

For Post Method....Sending xml example

```
NSString * xmlString = @"<Envelope><Body>............</Body></Envelop";

NSURL * serviceUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://...............url"];
NSMutableURLRequest * serviceRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:serviceUrl];
[serviceRequest setValue:@"text/xml" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-type"];

[serviceRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[serviceRequest setHTTPBody:[xmlString dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding]];

//    response hear-----------------
NSURLResponse *response;
NSError *error;
NSData *urlData=[NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:serviceRequest returningResponse:&response error:&error];
NSString *strdata=[[NSString alloc]initWithData:urlData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]; 
NSLog(@"%@",strdata);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try to give `curl` a look. It can be accessed from the command line as well as in build scripts.

Full documentation is available through `man curl` on the command line.